# Sometimes Latex appears to waste some space ; can this be avoided?

Tags: formatting

I'm writing an academic paper using `LaTeX`. I've noticed that sometimes `LaTeX` will waste some space. By "waste" I mean: in the first column of a certain page, the lines between 485 and 500 are empty. This is a relevant amount of space, since the paper has a limit of 6 pages.

I think that this is related with a listing that is currently displaying on the same page, but in the second column. They do intersect each-other somewhat. Removing that listing does prevent this, but I need the listing and `LaTeX` decides its position.

I've prepared a scheme of how that page is currently looking:

[image]

In a previous search, I saw someone mentioning a `\vspace{-3px}` trick. I have tried that trick with no results. I've tried with multiple values, and either the text does not move (e.g. with value -75px) or the text moves too much and overrides the text in the above section (e.g. with value -80).

I also tested removing the "another section" header. This makes the text go up and occupy the empty space, but new empty space moves to the bottom of that page, so there's still a lot of waste.

How can I improve this?

Comment: If you re-ask this on a appropriate site, please include a small but compileable test document so people can reproduce your problem and suggest solution which will actually work for your specific case.

Comment: latex only adds space where specified. If you showed a small example that produces space that you do not expect then someone would debug it for you, as it is, there is no real answer.

Comment: if the listing is unbreakable and can't float, then it doesn't fit into the first column LaTeX can only put space before or after the "another section", and which one it does depends on the "flush bottom" setting.

Comment: I would guess that you are using a flushbottom style so latex has to place text at the bottom of the page, so the only way to fill your "wasted" space would be to split the listing between the bottom of column a and top of column 2. You have probaly specified that listings can not be split.

Comment: You show very well the true issue in your scheme. In you can fit only two big unbreakable boxes in a column, then the only solution is left a huge gap at bottom or a huge gap between the boxes. By default LaTeX try the second to maintain the bottom margin. Although sometimes is better a huge gap in the bottom than in middle of the page, the solution is not choose between the bad and the worst, but if possible, the redesign of the the contents to allow as many break points as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You presumably have something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
abc\\abc\\abc\\abc

\section{Another section}
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc


\begin{minipage}{.7\columnwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}\vrule%


\subsection{A subsection}
abc

\end{document}
```

LaTeX is expanding the text in all but the last column to fill each column, just as it justifies the text in a paragraph expanding space in all but the last line of a paragraph.

So you can either disable this, so allowing each column to be set its natural length, adding

`\raggedbottom` to the preamble produces

[image]

where the column break occurs at the same place, but the first column is allowed to be short with the extra space at the end.

Or you could change the formatting of the listing. allowing a column break within the listing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
%\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
abc\\abc\\abc\\abc

\section{Another section}
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc\\
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc


%\begin{minipage}{.7\columnwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
aa
bb
cc
\end{lstlisting}
%\end{minipage}\vrule%


\subsection{A subsection}
abc

\end{document}
```